# Alternative types of keys for sub entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using Jpa with GAE. I have an Entity with collection of sub Entity as listed below.
In Entity A I'm using long as Id, In B I'm using Key as Id.

Now evreything works fine except that I need to import 8MB JAR file `appengine-api.jar` to my android app just for the Key class.
I tried extracting the jar and take only `Key.class` but it was messy because I had to add more classes that Key.class is using.

Is there another type of key that I can use?

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable
{
    @Id     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    private int a;

    @OneToMany    
    @Basic
    private List<B> bList;
    .
    .
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable 
{       
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    int b;
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using Java serialization to send data between your Android app and your App Engine app. You really shouldn't be doing that - write a proper interface on App Engine, and consume it on Android instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, [Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key) is the only class of this kind that is available. It has no superclass or meaningful interface you may use instead.